# Is there a java/JS library which can compare two json files and produce comparison result as html?

Tags: javascript, java, html, json

The idea behind the question is to have some library/tool which can compare two json strings and produce comparison result as html. E.g. the way some online comparison tools do.

Comment: Have you actually tried looking for it?

Comment: I suggest look into union and intersection between two json objects.

Comment: @KooiInc yes I have. Unfortunately I was not able to find what I want.

Answer (score -1):

I've developed a free online open-source service that you could either use as is or use the library inside the source-code for your own purposes.

The result of the comparison has an "analysis tree" which I don't know if it is what you are looking for, but if it is at least "close" to it, you can use the source code and adapt it to your needs.

I've tried to make it as complete and flexible as possible, but if you find any case I haven't considered, please either submit an issue in Github, or even better, a PR with the change.

- The working product: http://json-compare.online *(link no longer working 2022-05-10)*
- The source code: https://github.com/diegopamio/json-similarity-score

Comment: The live site no longer seems to work; I broke the link so as to prevent it from generating traffic to a future spammer

Comment: Ouch, sorry ,thanks for the heads-up, apparently I didn't renew the domain from GoDaddy and now it is not working anymore. I'll see if I can spend some bucks on the domain again and bring it back.